# Find the expected value Maxwell distribution

Tags: probability, expectation

I'm asked to find the mean velocity of gas particles knowing that their velocity can be modeled by the Maxwell distribution whose probability function is given by :
$$
\mathrm{f}\left(\, \vec{v}\,\right) =
4\pi\,\left(\, m \over 2\pi\mathrm{k_{B}}T\,\right)^{3/2}v^{2}
\exp\left(\,-\,{v^{2}\over 2m\,\mathrm{k_{B}}T}\right)
$$
I guess there is some trick to apply, some change of variable to do or some already-known distribution function to link to but I didn't manage to find it on my own so any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I should have added that m is the mass of the particle, K is Boltzmann's constant & T absolute temperature

Comment: 'Technically', $\vec{v}$ is the $velocity$ and $v \equiv \left\vert\,\vec{v}\,\right\vert$ is the $rapidity$. In this sense, the "mean velocity of gas particles" $\left\langle\,\vec{v}\,\right\rangle$ vanishes out. It's $\vec{0}$.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the Maxwell distribution for speed, $0$ to $\infty$. Think of it as $av^2e^{-bv^2}$, where $a$ and $b$ are messy constants.

We want $\int_0^\infty av^3 e^{-bv^2}\,dv$. Maybe make the change of variable $v^2=t$. Then $2v dv=dt$, and we want 
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{a}{2} te^{-bt}\,dt.$$
To finish, one integration by parts will do it.

Comment: You are welcome. I imagine there is no problem now that you hve a start. But if you wish I can write full detail.